# Unable to save data to localStorage using Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, local-storage, requirejs

I'm trying to save some data to localStorage while working on the Backbone.js framework together with Require.js.

However, I get the following error:

`Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified`

Any clue to what could have caused this error?
A quick Google revealed that Backbone.sync has to be set but doesn't the localStorage adapter do that for me already? What am  I missing?

Here are some relevant code snippets:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    // Major libraries
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery.min',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore.min',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone.min',

    // Require.js plugins
    text: 'libs/require/text',

    // Backbone.js plugins
    localstorage: 'libs/backbone/localstorage.min',

    // Just a short cut so we can put our html outside the js dir
    // When you have HTML/CSS designers this aids in keeping them out of the js directory
    templates: '../templates'
  }
});
```

...

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/score',
    'localstorage'
], function(_, Backbone, ScoreModel, Store){
    var ScoreCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ScoreModel,
        localStorage: new Store("ScoreCollection")
    });
    return ScoreCollection;
});
```

...

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone){
    var ScoreModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    });
    return ScoreModel;
});
```

-- EDIT --

Routes are as follows:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/scores/list',
    'views/scores/add'
], function($, _, Backbone, ScoreListView, ScoreAddView){
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            'scores': 'showScores',
            'scores/add': 'addScore',
            '*actions': 'defaultAction'
        }
    });

    var initialize = function(){
        var app_router = new AppRouter;

        app_router.on('route:showScores', function(){
            var scoreListView = new ScoreListView();
            scoreListView.render();
        });

        app_router.on('route:addScore', function(){
            var scoreAddView = new ScoreAddView();
            scoreAddView.render();
        });

        app_router.on('route:defaultAction', function(){
            console.log('No route');
        });

        Backbone.history.start();
    }
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

-- UPDATE --

Apparently, the model doesn't seem to be linked to the collection. Hence the localStorage set in the collection doesn't get applied to the model. Setting localStorage explicitly on the model makes it work. But does anyone know what I'm missing out?

Comment: Can we see your `routes`?

Comment: @Mohsen: edited to include routes. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This error](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1491) is thrown by the default implementation of Backbone.sync when it is called on a model and its url function is undefined. `Backbone.sync` is called implicitly by other functions like saving a model.

If you were using server-side storage, you'd want to set a url on your models. However, with localStorage, you'll need to override the `Backbone.sync` method altogether so that save, update and destroy functions will translate to operations on the localStorage adapter. I haven't used the backbone localStorage plugin, but it looks like it should be overriding `Backbone.sync`: https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage/blob/master/backbone.localStorage.js#L208

Try some sanity checks to make sure the plugin is loaded and the override function is being executed.

Comment: I know bout the Backbone.sync issue. However, backbone-localstorage.js seems to already override it. The problem comes with using backbone.localstorage TOGETHER with require.js.

Comment: Ok. How about making localStorage a dependency of your model definition?

Comment: Have you tried using the [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)? It may be needed in this case for the override to work globally as intended.

Comment: Take a look at my edit. Apparently, the problem seems to be with my models not being associated with the collection.